# changing text after period, in an endless cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text that I want to change after a certain period of time. I have this working:

```
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {

    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    }
};

var messages = [
    "sleep",
    "eat",
    "drink",
    "read",
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
```

See the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aushbfyL/1/)

My question:
I want to keep repeating the messages. In other words, when the last message is displayed, to start the cycle again from the first message creating an endless cycle. What needs to be changed / added to the code?

Comment: maybe instead of messages.pop(), you can use messages[(i++)%n].

Comment: `messages.pop()` is removing your array elements, instead use an index that you increment as LiranBo suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

```js
var fadeLoop = function($el) {
    $el.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        var $next = $el.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) {
            $next = $el.siblings(":first");
        }
        $next.fadeIn(1000, function() {
            fadeLoop($next);
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#elm1").siblings().hide();
    fadeLoop($("#elm1"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Things to do:
<div >
<span id="elm1">sleep</span>
<span id="elm2">eat</span>
<span id="elm3">drink</span>
<span id="elm4">read</span>
  </div>
```

Source : http://jsfiddle.net/KWmgf/

Answer (score 4):

Use `counter` with `%`

```js
var counter = 0;

function nextMsg() {
  $('#message').html(messages[counter % messages.length]).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
  ++counter;
};
var messages = [
  "sleep",
  "eat",
  "drink",
  "read",
];
$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Things to do: <span id="message"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: You don’t need `.reverse()` in this answer. The asker only used `reverse` because in his original code, he used `messages.pop()` to get the last element each time.

Comment: Thanks, this works great!!! Like Manoj Kumar's answer below too because it gives the capability of easily changing anything you want ie. message, color, image, etc.

Comment: because it has the added advantage of changing anything you want, not just the message. Although I understand my question referred to the message.

Comment: I realize that. But it is an added advantage don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rayon. I am actually using your solution, but know I can use the other if I want to also change something else.

Comment: @Eddy, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 2):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aushbfyL/2/) maybe.

**JS**

```
var i=0;

function nextMsg() {
    $('#message').html(messages[i]).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    i = (++i)%messages.length;
};

var messages = [
    "sleep",
    "eat",
    "drink",
    "read",
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
```

Comment: thanks!! Take away .reverse() and it runs from "sleep" to "read".